# After a row is selected in a table view how do I access the rows not selected text label to chage its color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

After a table View is displayed and a row is selected I want to change the color of all the non-selected rows table text label   color to blue..  Current within the case statement I can change the current row selected text label but with that case I don’t know how to access the other rows text label.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
          //******* NEED TO CHANGE ALL OTHER ROWS TEXT LABEL TO BLUE
          break;
        case 1:
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
          //******* NEED TO CHANGE ALL OTHER ROWS TEXT LABEL TO BLUE 
          break;
        default:
          break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Managing cell selection state from your table view's delegate is going to be unnecessarily difficult. You could store the index path of the selected cell, call the table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to get the formerly selected cell, and reset the label's color. However you don't know that the formerly selected cell is even still visible or loaded.

Better to use a UITableViewCell subclass which implements `setSelected:` to update its own view. That way your table view delegate only needs to set the cell's selected property and the cell is responsible for updating its own view appropriately. That will also allow you to implement `perpareForReuse` to reset your cells' views so that you don't need to worry about reusing a formerly selected cell and unexpectedly displaying a cell in a selected state.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable, e.g. an `NSInteger` called `selectedCell`, that tracks the selected cell. Change it to the selected cell and then reload the visible cells. 
In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you check the variable and style the label accordingly.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectedCell = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thus, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
// format the cell...
if (indexPath.row==self.selectedCell) {
    // style your cell for selected state
}
else {
    // style your cell for non-selected state
}
```

Cheers,
Sascha

Comment: Thanks for you fast response.. I am still a bit confused about tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  part.. Calling the method its always pointing to indexPath which is allways the cell selected. Do I call tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: using the previous row that I save and how do i do that.. Hope this question makes sense..

Comment: No need to call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It is done automatically by the call to `[tableView reloadData]` above.

Comment: Thanks so much for [tableView reloadData]... Got it working perfectly now!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You might want to consider clicking that check mark to mark the answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [self setSelectedImageAndTextColorForTableCell:indexPath :tableView];
}

//THIS METHOD IS USED TO RESET THE SELECTED COLORS FOR UIIMAGEVIEW AND UILABEL------
- (void)setSelectedImageAndTextColorForTableCell:(NSIndexPath *)aIndexPath 
               :(UITableView *)aTableView {
    if (!self.LastIndexPath_) {
        if (aTableView == mTableView_) {
            [self setLastIndexPath_:aIndexPath];
        }
    }
    if (self.mLastIndexPath_.row != aIndexPath.row) {
        //If Old Cell.

      UITableViewCell *lOldCell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.mLastIndexPath_];
      UILabel *lLabel_=(UILabel*)[lOldCell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
      [lLabel_ setTextColor:RGB_A(35, 30, 32, 1)];

      //If User touches on new cell.

      UITableViewCell *lNewCell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:aIndexPath];
      UILabel *lLabel_ = (UILabel*)[lNewCell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
      [lLabel_ setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
      self.mLastIndexPath_ = aIndexPath;


    }else {
        UITableViewCell *lNewCell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:aIndexPath];
        if (aTableView == mTableView_) {
            UITableViewCell *lNewCell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:aIndexPath];
            UILabel *lLabel_ = (UILabel*)[lNewCell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            [lLabel_ setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            self.mLastIndexPath_ = aIndexPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    if (nil==cell)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)] autorelease];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=CLEAR_COLOR;
        //Configure cell format for the tableView,
        //Same format for all the three sections.
        int tagCount = 1;
        CGFloat lXCoord = 5,lYCoord = 7,lWidth = 100/*,lHeight = 18*/;
//      for (tagCount = 1; tagCount <= 1; tagCount++) {
            UILabel *lUILabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
                lUILabel.frame = CGRectMake(lXCoord+10, 0, lWidth, 34);
            lUILabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lUILabel.textColor = RGB_A(35, 30, 32, 1);
           lUILabel.highlightedTextColor=WHITE_COLOR;
            lUILabel.font = FONT_OPENSANS_REGULAR(14);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lUILabel];
            [lUILabel setTag:tagCount];
            RELEASE_NIL(lUILabel);
//      }
        UIImageView *lUIImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            lUIImageView.frame = CGRectMake(lXCoord+100, lYCoord, 45, 29);
       [lImageView_ setHighlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPad_BuildInspectionDetails_%@_Selected.png",[[mDamageTableArray_ objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
      [lImageView_ setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPad_BuildInspectionDetails_%@_Normal.png",[[mDamageTableArray_ objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
        cell.accessoryView=lUIImageView;
        [lUIImageView setTag:tagCount + 1];
        RELEASE_NIL(lUIImageView);
        UIView *lSelectedView_ = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        lSelectedView_.backgroundColor =SELECTED_CELL_COLOR_GM;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = lSelectedView_;
    }
    //cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}
 - Note :-
 Use setHighlightedImage property for UIImageView `enter code here`& highlightedTextColor for UILabel.
 you can see highlighted image and highlighted text color if you select a row in UITableView
This will help you.
Happy Coding...`
```